# Whenever I try to install conda on my Pycharm I get an error, so how will I install conda on my pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for menuinst (from conda)

Comment: This link may help you solve the problem: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/#:~:text=Configuring%20a%20conda%20environment%20in%20PyCharm,-In%20the%20Settings&text=Select%20Preferences.,dialog%20box%2C%20select%20Conda%20Environment.

Comment: can you share your steps how you are proceding

Comment: I used the command "pip install conda" within the pycharm terminal

Comment: Please specify exactly what commands you're running, and their output. See [ask], [help/on-topic].